# To find length of an array in typescript(Angular application)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Mv6.png)

Need the length of this array.
Any suggestions

Comment: Please next time do a search before. You can literally copy past what you're saying "Need the length of this array" into [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Need+the+length+of+this+array.&oq=Need+the+length+of+this+array.&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160j33i22i29i30.1868j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and got the answer. Even for you it would have been quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [length property](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-length/#:%7E:text=length%20is%20a%20property%20of,can%20be%20returned%20like%20so.&text=The%20assignment%20operator%2C%20in%20conjunction,in%20an%20array%20like%20so.)

```js
console.log([{}, {}, {}].length)
```